# Python scripts output status (if failed or ran with success) in YML file

Tags: python, yaml, terraform, sh, aws-codebuild

do you know how can I have output logs when running a (my_script).py in a YML (CICD)?
I'm working with AWS codepipeline and codebuild and when my YML file runs, the CICD doesn't know if the (my_script).py failed or not because only the subprocess is failing, for CICD the (my_script).py executes and closes, therefore the pipeline ran with success even when the (my_script).py failed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and revise your question

Answer (score 0):

You can add `exit(1)` to exceptions and errors in the my_script.py script.exit(1) is abnormal operation causes the program to exit.

like this:

```
import sys

try:
    ...
    print("success")
    ...
except:
    sys.exit(1)
```